# Laplace inversion - general rule

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform

Given a constant $a\in\mathbb{C}$ and a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ with Laplace transform $F$, is there any chance to find the inverse Laplace transform of
the function $g_1:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{C}$ with $g_1(s)=\frac{F(s)}{sF(s)+a}$?

For sure, applying the Convolution Theorem for Laplace inversion, one may split
$\mathcal{L}^{-1}(g_1)=f*\mathcal{L}^{-1}(g_2)$ where $g_2(s)=\frac{1}{sF(s)+a}$. But since I don`t know the inverse Laplace transform of $g_2$, this is perhaps unrewarding.

Thanks for help!

Comment: It can't be _too_  simple, because at the start you need some condition that shows that $sF(s)+a\ne0$,  at least for $s>s_0$.

Comment: Lets assume, that $sF(s)+a\neq 0$ for every $s\in\mathbb{C}$ with $Re(s)\geq 0$.

Comment: Unless I'm missing some crucial detail, couldn't you use the Method of Residues?